# flowtype: how can i overload function return types by argument count/types?

Tags: javascript, overloading, flowtype

i want to define an overloaded function like

```
function first(n?: number) {
  if (number === undefined) {
    // returns a single Item
    return items[0];
  }

  // returns an array of Item
  return items.slice(0, n);
}
```

so that these statements type check:

```
const item: Item = first(); // no args, so return type is Item
const items: Array<Item> = first(5); // number arg, so return type is Array<Item>
```

flow knows that the first call to `first` is going to result in `n === undefined` (since it would complain if `undefined` wasn't valid for `n`) and it understands that it will then take the if branch, so i would think it could infer the return type is `Item`, but everything i've tried either lets anything pass or always fails.

any idea if this is possible? thanks in advance internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a complete solution for you, but I got partway there:

```
const items = [1, 2, 3];

type FirstType = ((_: void) => number) & ((n: number) => Array<number>);

const first: FirstType = (n?: number) => {
  if (n === undefined) {
    // returns a single Item
    return (items[0]: any);
  } else {
    // returns an array of Item
    return (items.slice(0, n): any);
  }
}

const a: number = first();
const b: Array<number> = first(2);
```

([tryflow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqAltgKYC2moAvKANoCMANKAEwMDMAugNzLYCeADoVAAxPACccAFX6DKAClkB9AFygAbrDwATAJQUAfKHQBXYgCNCo3QDJQ89CuNmLu8gYCCo0QEMeAHkfmonraXKgYOKCQYjgqIuLYUgIUtugA-A4mgS4GAN6IoPiQKRTklEbomoRR6IQ6oHkFBSCgooTYRqJYoF6gmHjoAObQggCSRMT5ja3tnbYEJJhUAAxsKl7oPCGTAL6ghNCYgg2gAJDN0x1d692ePqCwRWMkkycXs7LzpAB0mNB4KIRZEsGOhtGsNlsCttENCwlhcF4Mk5RMkovFZFs0PDQKYVB5vH4AhYDJQ0ThZIwQkA))

The `&` is an intersection type, and it means that `first` must satisfy *both* of those types. You can see that the calls to `first()` typecheck the way you want.

Unfortunately, it does not seem like Flow is currently able to typecheck the body of `first`. Note that I had to cast the return values through `any` to escape the typechecker. If you are willing to forgo typechecking in the body of your function, you can at least get it where the functions are called.

Comment: yeah... that works! i can't say i really understand why you need the `any` cast... but it works. thanks. and i didn't know about that "tryflow" page either, that's super useful for fiddling.

Comment: Just a warning though, casting through any is unsafe. You won't get typechecking for the return values.

Answer (score 1):

This may not work in the version of Flow that was current when you wrote OP, but trying against the latest version, I just discovered you can use `declare function` even in source files to avoid the horrific syntax of `((_: void) => number) & ((n: number) => Array<number>)`.

```
type Item = number;
const items: Array<Item> = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

declare function first(): Item;
declare function first(n: number): Array<Item>;
function first(n?: number): Item | Array<Item> {
  if (n === undefined) {
    // returns a single Item
    return items[0];
  }

  // returns an array of Item
  return items.slice(0, n);
}

const item: Item = first(); // no args, so return type is Item
const items2: Array<Item> = first(5); // number arg, so return type is Array<Item>
```

[Try Flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oDsCuCBGEBOA3AFADGA9mgM7BQCW8ClAXFAIJ54CGIAPHIgD4UUANoAGADRQAjFIBMUgMxSALAF1iRACYQSAG055oAMwxoSwWhSjHaeagAoAlC34JiO-YZNmLVtDZ2jmgsmDj4Lmwc3HwMAsSm5pbWtvbADmgA-KFYuHiRblAAPlFcvG5CAN5EUHTGUBkoyKhmOrZoEFpOUNW1tQD0-VBGwBh4VFCcUJS0aADmetBuNX0jYwH0iJTiGisAvkQrg8MQo+OUkwGGZVBk9cu1a+N0DJQAdJR6tCQQDpLoTmIB1IFGoL0QrgYwlSjkBUGOaDIkzwc0oUkoSKeAVAkDoF2W5CoNE2jDkLHYZVigmhQXSAFY4QjcvhkXN0ZjTusoDjoLQLhSYhUgA)

For class methods, the only way I've found is to declare the field type separately with the ugly `&` syntax (doesn't matter whether you use `declare` before the field declaration or not):

```
class Foo {
  foo: ((x: number) => string) & ((x: string) => number)
  foo(x: number | string): number | string {
    if (typeof x === 'number') return String(x)
    else return Number(x)
  }
}

const foo = new Foo()
const a: number = foo.foo('1')
const b: string = foo.foo(2)
```

[Try Flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDNEC5oAp8APPAOwFcBbAIwFMAnASmgF4A+aCAF3oEtSA5swBkBYnm59BzdtAo0GjdFkTi5VOvWgAfTj35CyGhjr1SBKZRl6YCXAJ4AHWvFtFWLFtADk8zd+Z6Wi5yelJoAGV9QWIlDAxaEAhaaCCQsOgAOWN6WOUAX1RC1GB4Um4VJC9SWgB3OFUlUvKuaDAjBS0vbHgAOh78bwBGAJKyiuoJaItuxH7VACZGIA)

Comment: Worth noting that when you use `declare` inline like that, flow will assume your function abides by the declared signature; so if your actual function is changed in a way that changes the signature, flow won't report an error